# Copying row info from one sheet to another, based on cell input

Tags: vba, excel

I havent coded in many years so ill do my best at communicating my objective.

I have a Master sheet that contains a list of many projects (listed in the Master with their own cell) that likewise have their own numbered sheets. This Master has info that pertains to all other projects in the rows, that when selected under the appropriate cell, will copy that rows info to the next available row in the applicable project sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim nextrow As Long, lastrow As Long, i As Long

nextrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
nextrow = Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
nextrow = Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
nextrow = Sheet6.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
nextrow = Sheet7.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
nextrow = Sheet8.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
nextrow = Sheet9.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
nextrow = Sheet10.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
nextrow = Sheet11.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
nextrow = Sheet12.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
nextrow = Sheet13.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
nextrow = Sheet14.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
nextrow = Sheet15.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
nextrow = Sheet16.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
nextrow = Sheet17.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
lastrow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C5:C" & lastrow)) Is Nothing Then
    If Target <> vbNullString Then
        i = Target.Row
        Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("A" & nextrow)
    End If
End If
```

This the previous 6 lines of code are repeated for every sheet number until it gets to the last sheet (Sheet 17 and cell Q), and then theres the:

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
end Sub
```

This works, however when it copies the info over, it replaces the existing info rather than place it in the next available row. This is the case EXCEPT for whatever the last project sheet is. The last sheet works as intended.

Comment: It is just that you **overwrite** `nextrow` at every calculation that you made on the start, so you'll only have this in facts `nextrow = Sheet17.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`.

Comment: Why are you setting `nextrow` so many times?  Effectively, the only value `nextrow` will ever have is `Sheet17.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` since that's the last call.  Therefore, when you are pasting to the next available range in Sheet 1, it's going to be based on that sheet17.  (You could literally remove the first 14 or so `nextrow = ...` and the same outcome would occur).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just that you **overwrite** `nextrow` at every calculation that you made on the start, so you'll only have this in facts `nextrow = Sheet17.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`.

You need to change the structure like this :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim nextrow As Long, lastrow As Long, i As Long
lastrow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

nextrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C5:C" & lastrow)) Is Nothing Then
    If Target <> vbNullString Then
        i = Target.Row
        Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheet1.Range("A" & nextrow)
    End If
End If


nextrow = Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C5:C" & lastrow)) Is Nothing Then
    If Target <> vbNullString Then
        i = Target.Row
        Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Copy Destination:=Sheet5.Range("A" & nextrow)
    End If
End If

nextrow = Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
'And so ON....
```

---

Or with an Array of Worksheets' Objects :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim NextRow As Long, LastRow As Long, i As Long, Sh() As Variant, Ws As Worksheet
LastRow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

ReDim Sh(1 To 15, 1 To 2)
Set Sh(1, 1) = Sheet1:      Sh(1, 2) = "C5:C"
Set Sh(2, 1) = Sheet5:      Sh(2, 2) = "D5:D"
Set Sh(3, 1) = Sheet4:      Sh(3, 2) = "E5:E"
Set Sh(4, 1) = Sheet6:      Sh(4, 2) = "F5:F"
Set Sh(5, 1) = Sheet7:      Sh(5, 2) = "G5:G"
Set Sh(6, 1) = Sheet8:      Sh(6, 2) = "H5:H"
Set Sh(7, 1) = sheet9:      Sh(7, 2) = "I5:I"
Set Sh(8, 1) = sheet10:     Sh(8, 2) = "J5:J"
Set Sh(9, 1) = sheet11:     Sh(9, 2) = "K5:K"
Set Sh(10, 1) = sheet12:    Sh(10, 2) = "L5:L"
Set Sh(11, 1) = sheet13:    Sh(11, 2) = "M5:M"
Set Sh(12, 1) = Sheet14:    Sh(12, 2) = "N5:N"
Set Sh(13, 1) = Sheet15:    Sh(13, 2) = "O5:O"
Set Sh(14, 1) = sheet16:    Sh(14, 2) = "P5:P"
Set Sh(15, 1) = Sheet17:    Sh(15, 2) = "Q5:Q"

For k = LBound(Sh, 1) To UBound(Sh, 1)
    Set Ws = Sh(k, 1)
    NextRow = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(Sh(k, 2) & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target <> vbNullString Then
            i = Target.Row
            Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).Copy Destination:=Ws.Range("A" & NextRow)
        End If
    End If
Next k

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If that's basically going to be one big loop (just changing the sheet each time), perhaps he could use an Array to store the Sheet names/indices and loop through that?  Would like `mySheets() = Array("Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3",...,"Sheet19")`  then `for i = lbound(mysheets) to ubound(mySheets)...mySheets(i).Cells(rows.count,"A").End(xlUp).Row+1`. ...etc, etc?  Or is it tricky working with sheet names as an array?

Comment: It might be possible with the actual names of the sheets (here `Sheet1` is not the name, it is the object), but not with the index (as it can change if you change the order of the sheets). Let's see what the OP says but I admit (personally) I'd prefer to use objects here because the names of the sheets may change but this Object reference won't.

Comment: That's what I was thinking (that you could use an array with the "Sheet1" name, but not the index).

Comment: Though, It might be possible with an array of Worksheets' Objects! See the edit!

Comment: So saying im not too familiar with arrays is probably obvious by my inadvertent redundancy and inability to notice the nextrow getting overwritten. But I wont be adding projects at a rate that it will be difficult to edit the code once I get a handle on it, but the sheet numbers will change, as well as the cell range such as C5:C, which is the target cell that I want activated for that project number. The next project will be D5:D, and so on... so the sheet number and cell number are paired.

Comment: Ok, I added a column to the array to include range basis (`C5:C`), take a look at the edit. FYI, **`:`** is used to place 2 code lines in the same row, I used it for a better readability of the definition of the array!

Comment: Perfect! : is what I was needing to understand to pair the sheet with the cell!

Comment: @MJD : Glad I could help! ;) As you are new to SO, just a few pointers : When your problem is solved, you can validate the answer by clicking in the tick right under the up/down vote arrows. Use up/down votes on each posts(Q or A) that you find useful/useless(or bad quality). And take a look : stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (even if this question was fine, it is always useful to know about those)